# Bypassing length limit of JQL

Tags: rest, jira, jql

I have to run a rather complex set of queries with many `OR` operators and long lists in [`IN`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-ININ) statements which I have to create dynamically. Overall the query will be well beyond 2000 characters, most likely even more than 5 or 6K.

My assumption is that the limit on JQL is because of the limit of http `GET` requests. Is there an alternative to pass JQL to Jira ? At the moment I use `rest/api/2/search?jql=...` from a Java program.

I know there is an approach that involves defining and using filters and thereby moving the lengthy parts from JQL to the filters. But in my case this would make me create lots of temporary filters and delete them afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [POST](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.4.2/#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest) search request has no limitation by JQL length

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see this alternative to `GET`. I can confirm this is working, I `POST`ed a 10,000 character long query to the REST endpoint and Jira was able to process it.